# How can we do authorization (roles and permissions) in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

For different roles with there permissions example admin , moderator , user

All these roles have different permissions for accessing pages and functionalities

How can I implement this in frontend

I am using react redux as my front end

Comment: provide code and what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access and Identity management are typically not features which are solely handled at the front-end.

Your user should authenticate itself against a back-end which then grants a role to your user (which you can then use to show features which are only applicable to this role). However to avoid users from using features they have no rights to, you should validate on the back-end every request they do.

This gives you the flexibility to change a user's role on the fly and invalidate their access to the application when necessary.